# Countdown by pressing a button

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, count

How can I add a countdown in this script, by pressing the left mouse button? Every click counts minus 1. 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 example? This currently does not work in this script, and I do not understand the problem.

```js
#pragma strict
 
 var myTrigger : GameObject;
 var myObject : GameObject;
 var countAmmo : int = 10 ;
 
 private var score : int = 10;
 var guiScore : GUIText;
 
 function Start ()
 {
 
 guiScore.text = "Score: 10"; 
 
 }
     
     
     
     function Update()
      {
 
       if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))  
 
          countAmmo = countAmmo -1;
          score = countAmmo -1;        
         
           if(countAmmo == 0)
           if(score == -1)
         
                   
          {         
             myObject.SetActive(false);    
          }
          
          else
          
          {
           
           guiScore.text = "Score: -1";
           
         
          
             myObject.SetActive(true);
          } 
      
   
      
      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which language this is or in which context you are trying to achieve that, but looking at your code it seems that its only a problem with some brackets in your if-clauses. Try it, no guarantee that it's working.

```
#pragma strict

var myTrigger : GameObject;
var myObject : GameObject;
var countAmmo : int = 10 ;

private var score : int = 10;
var guiScore : GUIText;

function Start ()
{
    guiScore.text = "Score: 10"; 
}

function Update()
{
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))  
        {
            countAmmo = countAmmo -1;
            score = countAmmo -1;  
            guiScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();

           if(countAmmo <= 0)
           {
               if(score == -1)
               {
                   myObject.SetActive(false);   
               } else {
                   guiScore.text = "Score: -1";
               }

              myObject.SetActive(true);
           }  
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried but the script is not working.
Here I can not show pictures I block.

I put a link to show the images, to understand the problem better. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/959673/countdown-by-pressing-a-button.html

Comment: Ok, I am not quite familiar with Unity, but if you want to update the text on the screen for the counter, you have to do that in your code... add a guiScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString(); in your if-clause ... see my edited post above!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
guiScore.text = "Score: -1";
```

Should be:

```
guiScore.text = "Score:" + score;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma strict

 var myTrigger : GameObject;
 var myObject : GameObject;
 var countAmmo : int = 10 ;

 private var score : int = 10;
 var guiScore : GUIText;

 function Start ()
 {

 guiScore.text = "Score: " + score.toString();

 }

     function Update()
      {

       if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))  

          countAmmo--;
          score = countAmmo - 1;        

       if(countAmmo == 0)
       {
          if(score == -1)      
          {         
             myObject.SetActive(false);  
          }
          else
          {
           guiScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
           myObject.SetActive(true);
          } 
      }
  }
```